# python requests: how to define a OR parameter

Tags: python, parameters, logical-operators, python-requests

I am using the requests module in python to construct URLs for API queries. Following is the code that I am using:

```
Params = {'q':'3145','organism':'9606'}
results = requests.get("http://www.pathwaycommons.org/pc2/search.xml",params=Params)
print results.url  #http://www.pathwaycommons.org/pc2/search.xml?q=3146&organism=9606
```

I want to add an OR condition to the q parameter (q = 3145 or 177). The ultimate url would be `http://www.pathwaycommons.org/pc2/search.xml?q=3146|177&organism=9606`. If I used `Params = {'q':['3145','177'],'organism':'9606'}`, the output url is `"http://www.pathwaycommons.org/pc2/search.xml?q=3146&q=177&organism=9606"`. I have not found any information about how to define a parameter dictionary for an OR condition. Could anybody give some idea?

Thank you in advance.

Wendy

Comment: the `&` symbol in the query string is not a logical AND operator, it's merely a separator. Standard allows using a semicolon instead. If you consider this, you'll see that "|" is not an OR operator, it's just a part of the value for `q` parameter: `q=3146|177`. The fact that it's interpreted as OR is completely specific to that particular API, they could've chosen almost any other symbol for that, for example `q=3146,177`

Comment: @Sergey,thank you very much for clarifying this.

Answer (score 5):

This is the first time I've seen this "OR" syntax, so I'm not sure if it's standard.

Anyways, you *could* just `join` the parameter list to create a string, like so:

```
params = {
  'q': '|'.join(['3145','177']),
  'organism': '9606'
}
```